# Nodejs: write list into csv

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

How do I write a list into a csv file? I couldn't find any good examples for this case. I have a list which looks like this:

```
list1 = ["label1", 100, 100, "label2", 200, 200, "label3", 300, 300];
```

And I want it to look like this (preverred):

[image]

or like this:

[image]

My approach was going with `var csv = require('fast-csv');`, but its a pretty old library and also it didn't work correctly for me.

```
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('data.csv');
csv.write(list1, {true}).pipe(ws);
```

What is the best approach in 2018?

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv-write package.

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;

let list1= ["label1",100,200,"label2",300,400,"label3",500,600];

let headerRec = [];
let records = [];

for(let i of list1){
 if(typeof(i)=="string"){
   let key = i
   let index = list1.indexOf(i);
   headerRec.push({id:i,title:i}); 
   records.push({[i]:list1[index+1]});
   records.push({[i]:list1[index+2]});
}

}
const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
  path: './file.csv',
  header: headerRec
});
csvWriter.writeRecords(records)      
.then(() => {
    console.log('...Done');
});
```